# C# How to get reference to Custom Typed DataRow when using a DataView?

Tags: c#, datarow, dataview, datarowview

I am using custom typed MyDataTable and MyDataRow. When I use DataView's DataRowView.Row (DataView and DataRowView are not customized), I get a reference to DataRow, instead of MyDataRow.

Which method in which class should I override to get a reference to MyDataRow?
I am using .NET 4.5

Comment: Have you tried simply casting, e.g.`(MyDataRow)DataRowView.Row`

Comment: That will work. I do not want to cast. I want DataRowView.Row to return MyDataRow.